# How do I make enumerate return an index as a u32 instead of usize?

Tags: rust

I see that when `enumerate` is called, the `index` value is returned as a `usize`. Why is this? and how can I make it return the index as another numeric type instead? Let's say u32?

Right now I have to do a manual cast to `u32`. For example:

```
let mut even_index: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
for (i, v) in vec![10,27,31,40,5].iter().enumerate() {
    if v % 2 == 0 {
        even_index.push(i as u32); // any way to avoid this?
    }
}
```

Is there a way to not have to manually perform the cast to `u32` and have `enumerate` return the index as `u32` instead?

I looked at the documentation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) and the documentation contains the following:

> enumerate() keeps its count as a usize. If you want to count by a different sized integer, the zip function provides similar functionality.

I looked at the `zip` function and it looks like it does something different so I do not understand why it is being suggested as an alternative when there is a need to count by a different sized integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use zip and range to do:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut even_index: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    for (i, v) in (0u32..).zip([10, 27, 31, 40, 5]) {
        if v % 2 == 0 {
            even_index.push(i);
        }
    }

    assert_eq!(even_index, [0, 3]);
}
```

Comment: Since `even_index` has type `Vec<u32>`, you can even omit the `u32` suffix in `0u32`. Rust is smart enough to figure out the types of numeric literals based on how they're used — in this case, you're pushing `i` to a `Vec<u32>`, which can only happen if `i: u32`. Alternatively, if you keep the `0u32`, you can omit the type of `even_index` altogether. In general Rust is good at type inference and you can give it the bare minimum it would need to reach the right conclusion, and it'll reach it.